# moving data from mysql to elasticsearch using logstash file configuration

Tags: logstash

I want to migrate a table from a MySQL database to elasticsearch, I use logstash and I write this config file but it does not work, can you help me fix the error 
thanks in advance 
this is the file configuraton
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu272.png)

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/new_schema?useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC"
    jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "password"

    statement => "SELECT * FROM tweecoms"
  }
}

output {
#stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "socialmed"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to add more information to your question, what is the error?

Comment: I committed the error in the configuration of the logstash file, if you can correct it to me i'll be thankful ;

Comment: What is the error in the logstash log file?

Comment: Try to change your `jdbc_driver_library` configuration to `jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar"`, as shown in the example on the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.0/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html)

Comment: i edited my post you can see the results in description image